# Get-SqlInstance : The operation failed on target server

Tags: powershell, sqlps

I am researching using SQLPS module; PowerShell version 3.0. When running **Get-SqlInstance**, I consistently get the following error.

```
PS 11/16/2015 08:34:29> $cred = Get-Credential
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:

PS 11/16/2015 08:44:28> $instance = Get-SqlInstance -MachineName SM1208 -Credential $cred
Get-SqlInstance : The operation failed on target server 'SM1208'. Verify that the target server is accessible and that the SQL Server 
Cloud Adapter service is running.
At line:1 char:13
+ $instance = Get-SqlInstance -MachineName SM1208 -Credential $cred
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SM1208:String) [Get-SqlInstance], SqlPowerShellRemoteOperationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoteOperationFailedError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.IaaS.GetSqlInstanceCommand
```

I have tried this using localhost, the IP, and a different server that also hosts SQL Server instances. Also used the -Name to specify the instance name. Same error each time. SQL Server instance is running on the hosts.

```
PS 11/16/2015 08:44:55> Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `verify that (...) SQL Server Cloud Adapter service is running` ? And if it is, would it possibly be a firewall issue ?

Comment: Thanks. I guess the SQL Server Cloud Adapter is required... not sure why this would be forced on users.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, and confirmed by OP, it seems a needed service on the target host is missing:

> `Verify that (...) SQL Server Cloud Adapter service is running.`

Answer (score 1):

Try:
Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQL\machinename\instancename